# difference between "didnt" and "havent"

Tags: difference

is the sentence "im didnt sleep well" right? or i should say "i havent sleep today well"? because translator says that both correct, when the rules say that "didnt" is the action that hasn’t been done and can’t be done anymore and "havent" we use when we talking about the past up until either the present or a specific time period. because if you follow this rule, it would be correct to use "didnt", but my teacher says to use "havent".

Comment: Forget the contractions, which are just adding to your confusion. For a non-negated sentence, we usually just use Simple Past: *I **slept** well.* But for a *negated* assertion we can either use Present Perfect: *I **have not slept** well* OR we can use "negated do-support": *I **did not sleep** well*. Note that the main verb is in ***past participle*** form *(**slept**)* in Perfect constructions, but we use the ***bare infinitive*** *(**sleep**)* in "do-support" constructions.

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect.

I didn't sleep well - is correct, note there is no "I'm". This refers to a specific time, which should be obvious from context.

I haven't slept well today - is correct. Note the word order. This means that you haven't slept well during today.

As a side note, the apostrophes in hadn't and didn't are important.